# make error when cross compile Perl for ARM

Tags: perl, cross-compiling

I have successfully configure perl for cross comile by using configure options:

```
./Configure -des -Dusecrosscompile \
    -Dtargethost=172.17.185.91 \
    -Dtargetdir=/home/perl/ \
    -Dtargetuser=root \
    -Dtargetarch=arm-linux \
    -Dcc=arm-linux-gcc \
    -Dusrinc=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/include/ \
    -Dincpth=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/include/ \
    -Dlibpth=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/lib/
```

And the configure script tell me "Now you must run 'make'." But I encounter such as error when I make:

```
`sh  cflags "optimize='-O2'" miniperlmain.o`  miniperlmain.c
  CCCMD =  arm-linux-gcc -DPERL_CORE -c -DOVR_DBL_DIG=14 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O2  -Wall 
In file included from perl.h:38,
                 from miniperlmain.c:40:
config.h:4425:12: error: operator '==' has no left operand
In file included from miniperlmain.c:40:
perl.h:713:14: error: operator '>=' has no left operand
... ...
```

In config.h, some macro is left blank, for example:

```
#define INTSIZE         /**/
#define LONGSIZE        /**/
#define SHORTSIZE       /**/
... much more ...
```

And I think it is the undefined macro result in the make error. I have no idea how to fix it. Why the macro is blank even if successfully configure?
Are there some guides to cross compile Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the easiest way to cross compile Perl for arm-linux.Please refer to [Cross-compiling perl](http://perlcross.berlios.de/index.html). It's a great work! It saved my life.

Just according to instructions that give, you can get what you want. You may encounter such error when 'make':

```
pp_sys.c:78: error: non-thread-local declaration of 'h_errno' follows thread-local declaration
```

Simply comment that line.
Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Cross` directory that features a `README` file that includes the following instructions for arm-linux:

```
1)  You should be reading me (README) in perl-5.x.y/Cross

2)  Make sure you are in the Cross directory.

3)  Edit the file 'config' to contain your target platform information.

4)  make patch  ## This will patch the existing source-tree.
5)  make perl   ## Will make perl
```

(Read the whole thing.)